# Why does PM2 not consider my app errored with a clear exit code 1?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, pm2, yarn-v2

I had 2 projects running on Node v16 and an old version of PM2. After upgrading node to v16, both stopped restarting on error. I've upgraded one to PM2 v5.2.0 and it fixed the issue.

However, the other project still does not restart. I tried testing using just an error thrown from the first function called in the project and it exits with code 1, but PM2 continues showing its status as `online`. Running it directly from bash makes it crash, so there's no good reason for PM2 not to detect that.

I start my process very simply - `pm2 start name=project-name yarn -- run start:prod`. Both projects are launched like this.

PM2's Github issues are full of the reports of this, but no one replies to most of them. Maybe someone who has run into this previously has tips?